# How to setup CCTV Surveillance using PC

Tags: home-surveillance

I've been wanting to setup a CCTV in my family small convenient shop. Since i've never setup one before, i would like some ideas, tips or advice from you guys who have experienced it or have ideas how to do so.

Here is what i've come up so far, I was thinking to get a IP camera, something [like this one](http://www.dse.co.nz/dse.shop/4cd24039003ce696273fc0a87f3b06af/Product/View/L6193) since the shop has Broadband with 3GB data caps. I have a desktop computer with 60GB of hard drive. I was thinking to connect the camera to PC and using pc's hard drive but to do so, i have to turn on my PC all day long 24/7 (worry it might blow my pc up and burn the shop at night lolz). Oh the camera is recorded when there's any movement though which is pretty cool. I know i need the software which i think i could just search around and download them.

Anyway if i use PC, how long can i record it with 60GB hard drive? Is there any other way without using PC? Does it consume alot of broadband data if i use IP camera? cos 3GB, i normally use up about 2GB and only 1GB left by the end of the month. By the way, i have wireless broadband though.

Please guys, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be ideal is a DVR kit. Basically, its a DVR with cameras and a monitor. You wire the cameras to the the DVR, it records. You can connect [this](http://www.frys.com/product/6134959?site=sr:SEARCH:MAIN_RSLT_PG) particular DVR up to a network and monitor it remotely as well as view it on the monitor that it comes with. You can also back up images to a USB drive from the DVR as well via a built in USB port. For a little more money you can purchase a wireless camera kit so you don't need to run cables.

EDIT: Yes, IP cameras use up a fair amount of bandwidth. About 3 cameras will max out a full T1 line. This will not affect your internal traffic very much though.